# VueJS warning in Laravel

Tags: vue.js

I am working on a Laravel app where VueJS integrated inside Larevel Blade file.  I added `app.js` file like below.

```
if(Request::is('admin/time')) {
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" async defer></script>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting error `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`.  If I visit VueJS component page I am not getting error. But if I visit other pages I am getting error.

I added `#app` is like below.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that a root element with the id "app" is added to your blade file?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. Yes I added `app` id. I added `app` id in a blade file. If I browse that page then I am not getting that error. But if I browse other pages then I am getting this error.

Comment: Okay, and you also configured the webpack.mix.js file?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. No, I didn't configur the `webpack.mix.js`  file. My Blade file is like below.

`@extends('layouts.admin.app')

@section('title', 'Time')

@push('css_or_js')
@endpush

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <time-component />
    </div>
@endsection`

Comment: In my opinion, the app element should define in your layout blade file, so that the whole application will have this `app` element. But if you are using the `app` element in non-layout files then make sure to include your compiled javascript file (app.js) in your all HTML views also, make sure you have a root element with an id of the `app`.

Comment: Also, if this is just a warning not an error then use defer in your script like this- `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`